# Deleting empty rows with Checkboxes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have previously asked a question to delete empty rows in a table where @Cooper helped get me the answer and worked perfectly.

[Empty Rows in between](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXwOZ.png)

The script I have been provided with is;

```
  `const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Potential Matrix");
  const rg=ss.getDataRange();
  const vs=rg.getValues();
  let d=0;
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){if(r.join('').length==0) {ss.deleteRow(i+1-d++);}});
  ss.insertRowBefore(1).getRange("1:1").clearFormat();
```

I was wondering if someone knows how to adjust this script slightly to take into account unchecked checkboxes?

[New Picture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QtSa.png)

Comment: What are you asking?Please show an image of the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Potential Matrix");
  const rg=ss.getDataRange();
  const vs=rg.getValues();
  let d=0;
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(r.join('').length==0 || r.join('')=='false') {
      ss.deleteRow(i+1-d++);
    }
  });
  ss.insertRowBefore(1).getRange("1:1").clearFormat();
```

Comment: Hi @Cooper, thanks for that. It doesn't seem to count the rows in between numbers 12, 13 and 14 as blank and therefore doesn't delete them. The original script you gave me worked when I didn't have checkboxes but now there are checkboxes it doesn't work. Is there any way of deleting rows including unticked checkboxes and empty data?

I have added 'New Picture for reference' in my original post to show what I mean

Comment: @SheaMurphy, just change the `if` condition to this: `if(r.join('').length==0 || r.join('')=='false' || r.join('')=='true')`.